# CTS run stops in Middle - AdbCommandRejectedException - insufficient permission for device

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-compatibility, device-compatibility

Iam executing Full CTS run (640 modules).But in between the device gets restarted and the device USB mode goes to charging the device from USB files transfer. So, CTS will stops executing because of device not available.

Solutions I tried :

1. I gave default USB configuration as Files Transfer. 
   So, This time after restarting it will be in Files Transfer mode. But requesting user for permission allow or deny to access the device  . Nothing but again manual input required here. So untill unless some one allow it the CTS run will be stopped.

Any solution for this.Its been many days I have stucked with this problem.